# Account with conflicting name exists locally

Tags: linux, ssh, fedora

When I login to a Fedora box through ssh, i get the following error:

```
Account with conflicting name exists locally
```

Anyone know how I can get rid if this? I think whatever issue that is, it's also keeping me from opening a Eclipse workspace I was working on before I lost network connectivity to this Fedora host.

Answer (score 1):

Use command: killall -u USER_NAME

Thanks to: http://www.webhostingresourcekit.com/831.html